# Are there wireless smart lights that can be directly controlled with a raspberry pi>

Tags: pi-zero-w

> I am new to raspberry pi, so I apologize in advance if this question
>   is very basic or is in the wrong place.

I want to create one of those wakes up alarm clocks that slowly brightens the light in the room when its time to wake up. They cost $80+ online so ideally, I want to do it for less than that.

My idea is to use a Phillips smart light and control it wirelessly using a Raspberry Pi zero, however, the main problem with that is that it appears to require using a Phillips smart hub which would raise the price by $60 and defeat the whole purpose of using this setup vs just buying a commercial product online.

Does anyone know of any light bulbs that can be directly controlled by a raspberry pi via Bluetooth or wifi?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you Google Phillips Hue, I believe you will find that the protocol has been reverse engineered, meaning you can immitate any component in the system.

Comment: There is a lot of light bulbs that they have just some smartphone app which you can hack and test what they're doing and imitate what they're doing by your raspberry pi. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=232133#p1421484